# .doc to .docx conversion in python

Tags: python, python-docx

i have been trying to use python and the win32com client to save multiple files from .doc to .docx (so i can then edit them with the python docx program) I run the below code and get a "finished with no errors and an exit code of 0" in pycharm. This is my first foray into Python.

After i run it i get 0 errors but the documents are still all .doc

```
from glob import glob
import re
import os
import win32com.client as win32
from win32com.client import constants

paths = glob('C:\test\*.doc', recursive=True)

def save_as_docx(path):
   
    word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
    doc = word.Documents.Open(path)
    doc.Activate ()
    
    
    new_file_abs = os.path.abspath(path)
    new_file_abs = re.sub(r'\.\w+$', '.docx', new_file_abs)
    
    
    word.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(
        new_file_abs, FileFormat=constants.wdFormatXMLDocument
    )
    doc.Close(False)

for path in paths:
    save_as_docx(path)
```

After this i get

"Process finished with exit code 0"
And all of the files are still .doc in the C:\test folder.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python)

Answer (score 6):

You should debug things a little by e.g. printing `paths` – your glob pattern is wrong: `'C:\test\*.doc'` is a string that has `C:`, then a tab character, then the rest. You'll need to use `r`aw strings to avoid backslash interpretation:

```
paths = glob(r'C:\test\*.doc', recursive=True)
```

Then, `recursive=True` does nothing since you're not using a double star:

```
paths = glob(r'C:\test\**.doc', recursive=True)
```

Finally, replacing the extension with `.docx` is better done with tools suited to the job, so all in all

```
from glob import glob
import os
import win32com.client as win32
from win32com.client import constants

def save_as_docx(path):
   
    word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
    doc = word.Documents.Open(path)
    doc.Activate ()
    
    new_file_abs = os.path.splitext(os.path.abspath(path))[0] + ".docx"
    
    word.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(
        new_file_abs, FileFormat=constants.wdFormatXMLDocument
    )
    doc.Close(False)

paths = glob(r'C:\test\**.doc', recursive=True)

for path in paths:
    save_as_docx(path)
```

should be closer to what you need.